# Strange layout on the main page with the iPad competition (I think)

Tags: support, status-bydesign, design, site-promotion

On the main page there appears to be some "additional content" and it looks as though it is related to an iPad.  However, I can't tell for sure because it looks like this:

[image: Main page view]

At first, I put it down to the fact that I'm using FF11 on Linux so clearly the "Ask Different" website would *Look Different* since no Apple products were harmed in the viewing of this page.

But then I happened to look at it using Safari Mobile on my iPad and it looked the same.

Is this how it ought to look?  There does appear to be something behind the main question bit - that black semi-circle is certainly suggestive of that fact.  Is the site telling me that I shouldn't use Firefox or Linux?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is intentional, the image is an iPad partially hiding behind the question view. If you click on the iPad you'll see that we're currently holding a contest, where the top contributors can earn iPads.

Comment: Ah, I've now scrolled down a bit further and can see the bottom of the iPad.  I still say that that is completely non-obvious.  Is that the criteria for being in the competition - can you spot that it's an iPad?

Comment: @AndrewStacey I'll admit that it does look like some sort of layout or formatting error to someone that doesn't recognize it, but I imagine most Apple fans will. If I were designing it I might have gone for something slightly different, but I think that it mostly does the job

Comment: Yes, now that I know what it is then I recognise it.  I think it might have been better to go for a black iPad just because the main site is so white-dominated as it is.  I was really just trying to find out if there was something hidden that I wasn't seeing.  From what you say, I conclude that there isn't and so I'll stop worrying about it.  Thanks.

Comment: @AndrewStacey We tried a black one first; it was way too harsh on the eyes (because of the extreme contrast with the rest of the site).